# Download multiple files over FTP using one connection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to download multiple files to memory with only one open connection.

I know from this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.keepalive – that `FtpWebRequest` defaults `KeepAlive` to true.

> if the connection to the server should not be destroyed; otherwise, false. The default value is true.

I have created this piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp23
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] files = FTPListTree("ftp://server.com", "user", "password");

            for (int i = 0; i <= files.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                string path = files[i].ToString();
                var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
                request.Timeout = 100000;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.ConnectionGroupName = "DownloadFilesGroup";
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 8;

                using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var ms = new MemoryStream();
                        stream.CopyTo(ms);
                        var a = ms.ToArray();
                        string ss = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a);
                        Console.WriteLine(ss);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static String[] FTPListTree(String ftpUri, String user, String pass)
        {

            try
            {
                List<String> files = new List<String>();
                Queue<String> folders = new Queue<String>();
                folders.Enqueue(ftpUri);

                while (folders.Count > 0)
                {
                    String fld = folders.Dequeue();
                    List<String> newFiles = new List<String>();

                    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fld);
                    ftp.Timeout = 20000;
                    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

                    using (StreamReader resp = new StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        String line = resp.ReadLine();
                        while (line != null)
                        {
                            newFiles.Add(line.Trim());
                            line = resp.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }

                    ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fld);
                    ftp.Timeout = 20000;
                    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

                    using (StreamReader resp = new StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        String line = resp.ReadLine();
                        while (line != null)
                        {
                            if (!Path.HasExtension(line))
                            {
                                String dir = newFiles.First(x => line.EndsWith(x));
                                newFiles.Remove(dir);
                                folders.Enqueue(fld + dir + "/");
                            }
                            line = resp.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                    files.AddRange(from f in newFiles select fld + f);
                }
                return files.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a proper way of doing dispose? I can't seem to find any documentation on if disposing the `response` or the response stream, will close the control connection, that the keepalive will keep open.

Is there any way I can log this when running this, so I can see the FTP calls? I don't have access to the FTP server myself.

**UPDATE**

I have actually tested this with a test FTP and the above code, even though it has `KeepAlive=true`, it uses new connection on every request. I have created an PoC with Fluent API: https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP.CSharpExamples/DownloadManyFiles.cs, that does it correctly: connect once, and downloads files. I had a feeling that it was the case with `FtpWebRequest`. I don't understand the `KeepAlive` and what it does. Maybe it reuses the TCP connection, which is a good thing in itself, but it uses the TCP connection to login on each request.

Does anybody know if this is even possible with `FtpWebRequest`, not logging in on each new request, like the Fluent FTP API? Am I missing something?

An example of the FTP log can be seen here
[image: FTP log]

FTP is FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the FTP connection reuse was not implemented in .NET Core:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23256

And as [`*WebRequest` API is actually obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest#remarks), it probably never will.

---

With .NET framework, it works as expected:
[FTP multiple files in C# without reestablishing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49012015/850848)

Comment: Many thanks for this. I didn't know of the obselete *WebRequest.